# How can I trigger click event in a for loop in Angular

Tags: angular

In the web app, I want to trigger a click event on file input field whenever user clicks the image. But my problem is how to click the specific file input. I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
    <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let subcat of subcatsName; let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">        
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" #fileInput [name]="i+'_pics'" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)" />
            <img *ngIf="!subcatsPics[i]" (click)="fileInput.click()" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Click+here+to+change+image" class="npix">
        </div>
    </div>

    onSelectedFile(event){
            this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0]
            this.preview(this.selectedFile)
        }
```

I am new to Angular and am confused on how to go about it.

Comment: use simple (click)="functionname"

Comment: @ViewChildren('fileInput') public fileInputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;


    onSelectedFile(event){
            const fileInput = this.fileInputs.find(input => input === ??? here maybe you can access to the selected input from the event received argument);
            this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0]
            this.preview(this.selectedFile)
        }

Comment: You code seemed to work fine for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbysve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -2):

**When you click on external button, it will click the other button,**

```css
.btn {
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDzMXqR8GWGDP3ddFBdl5O_e0Ngc-U86kY"> </script>

<button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="document.getElementById('extBtn').click()">External Button</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="alert('Clicked')" id="extBtn">Button</button>
```

This will work with the JavaScript and jQuery.